# Cross compile for ARM environment

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

I am working on an ARM computer:

Here is `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 413.08
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 0

Hardware    : ARM-Versatile Express
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

I have tried to compile this program from an x86 computer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello world!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Here is what I've done to compile this program:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static my_program.c
```

Here is the error message I get when I try to run it on ARM computer:

> Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

and here is the output of `file ./a.out`

```
./a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=0e39c5694c188b0e596666fe6503909394e72f44, not stripped
```

Comment: The error message is most likely coming from a shell. Are you using a shell script to run the compiler? Or is `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` a shell script?

Comment: Can you make sure the binary you are executing is for Arm ? `file ./a.out`

Comment: Here is the output of file: ./a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=0520a4e554f2c337d6cf525f6a1835e5dad593de, not stripped

Comment: What does the 'Features' line contain in the output for the `cat /proc/cpuinfo`command ? if it does look like this one: `Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm`, that is it does contain `vfp` features, your CPU does have support for hardware floating point, and you should use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`, not `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.

Comment: How are you launching the program on your target?

Comment: see my edits for full /proc/cpuinfo. I am launching the program by typing ./a.out